# How to auto-update a specific cell from another sheet weekly with a new entry? (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible to write a script that autoupdates cells with new enntries within a column?

e.g. "J2" gets updated, and I want a new entry in "C2" in another sheet.
Would it work for a whole column or row as well?

To be honest I'm quite a beginner in terms of coding, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow At this site you are expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing more research, if you have a problem you can post **what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. I suggest reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question and the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/6676466).

Comment: In short the answer is Yes.  What is the source of the new data?

Answer (score 0):

Place this in cell C2 of the sheet you want to have the new value:

```
=Sheet1!J2
```

If the sheet name is different, replace Sheet1 with the sheet's name.  If there is a space in the sheet name, place single quotes around the name, such as:

```
`='Responses ID'!J2`
```

IF you need to apply this to a column, there is a way to do this without copying the formula all the way down.  Placing this in cell C2 will apply the formula to the entire column:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK('Responses ID'!C2:C),,'Responses ID'!C2:C))
```

ARRAYFORMULA() works on and returns an array
IF() returns a one value if a conditio is true and a differnt one if it is false.  In this case we the condition is ISBLANK() which returns true if the cell passed is blank.  The IF() returns nothing for the true case (NOTE that this is not set to "" as Google Sheets places a value in the cell when this is the case.  By leaving the true value out, it returns nothing.).

If you want to make sure nobody deletes this formula by editing cell C2, you can "Hide" it in the Header row by adding a bot to it:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(A1:A)= A1, "My Header",IF(ISBLANK('Responses ID'!C2:C),,'Responses ID'!C2:C)))
```